# Is there a way to configure the default mirror for App::cpanminus (cpanm)?

Tags: perl, cpan, cpanm

I am aware you can easily configure cpan to use a specific mirror.  However I recently started using cpanm at the advice of a friend, and I can't seem to find a way to set the default mirror without specifying `--mirror http://cpan.metacpan.org` on the command line each time.

Is there an environment variable or a config file that I can set the default mirror?

As for why I would want to simply not use the default list of mirrors, I am an FI and we are firewalled to no end.  Only one mirror has been allowed through our firewall.

Comment: *"I an an FI"* Financial Institution? Faecally Incontinent? If your words matter then please don't use arcane abbreviations.

Comment: It sounds like it would be useful to download your own copy of a CPAN repository on a properly-connected system and sideload it to your isolated machine. Take a look at [`minicpan`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/CPAN-Mini-1.111016/bin/minicpan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cite from the [cpanm docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/lib/App/cpanminus/fatscript.pm#ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLES)

> ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
>
> PERL_CPANM_OPT If set, adds a set of default options to every cpanm
>   command. These options come first, and so are overridden by
>   command-line options.

So try: `export PERL_CPANM_OPT="--mirror http://cpan.metacpan.org"`